# Matlab - Evaluate Function from String

Tags: matlab, expression-evaluation

Some Matlab functions handle string functions representation as `f='a^x^b+sin(c*x)+d'` --i.e. Curve Fitting, Optimization, etc.--

Suppose the variables `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` and `x` are given. Is there any function for evaluating `f` from its string representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `eval(f)`, but using `eval` is really discouraged https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html

Comment: I created a [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179940/performance-of-eval-compared-to-str2func-to-evalulate-a-function-from-a-stri) to compare `eval` with `str2func`. `eval` is 50% slower even for just 1 evaluation.