# Performance of `eval` compared to `str2func` to evalulate a function from a string

Tags: matlab, performance, eval

[`eval`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) and [`str2func`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) are both able to evaluate a function represented by a string, f.e. `f='a^x+exp(b)+sin(c*x)+d'`:

- Using `eval`:

  ```
  y = eval(f)
  ```

  or (suggested by rahnema1)

  ```
  fHandle = eval(['@(x, a, b, c, d) ' f]);
  y = fHandle(x, a, b, c, d);
  ```
- Using `str2func`:

  ```
  fHandle = str2func(['@(x, a, b, c, d) ' f]);
  y = fHandle(x, a, b, c, d);
  ```

Which of both methods has the best performance?

**Remarks**

*Note that this benchmark is inspired on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178175/matlab-evaluate-function-from-string).*

Note that I'm aware that using `eval` and `str2func` is often bad practice[[1]](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/)[[2]](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) (as mentioned in the comments).

Comment: Good idea, but please mention in your answer how `eval` is undesirable for [reasons](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) more fundamental than performance

Comment: In which way is `eval` undesirable compared to `str2func` except for performance?

Comment: @m7913d In my answer to [the question which inspired your benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178175/matlab-evaluate-function-from-string/46178318?noredirect=1#comment79322513_46178318), I linked to the [documentation on why `eval` is undesirable](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html). Namely, it's hard to debug, it can unexpectedly overwrite workspace data, it isn't compiled for future runs (that's the performance aspect) and strings which are created by concatenation as inputs to `eval` can be hard to read. Can usually be avoided, so should be

Comment: @Wolfie I think those arguments are also - to some extent -  applicable to `str2func`, especially the last two items.

Comment: @m7913d See link in my first comment

Comment: @Luis Mendo Loren writes there that `str2func` is an alternative to `eval`, but I didn't understand why, what cause it be different? Why in that function Matlab can process and access variables rather than in `eval`?

Comment: @Adiel As I see it, `eval` and `str2func` do different things

Comment: I asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213509/why-is-eval-worse-than-str2func-to-evaluate-a-function-from-a-string) as I'm unsure which fundamental reasons do only apply to `eval` and not to `str2func`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** use `str2func`.

**Benchmark**

The benchmark will evaluate the function for `N` different values of `x`.

```
f='a^x+exp(b)+sin(c*x)+d';

Ns = linspace(1, 1000, 20);
timeEval = zeros(size(Ns));
timeEvalHandle = zeros(size(Ns));
timeStr2func = zeros(size(Ns));
for i=1:length(Ns)
  N = Ns(i);
  timeEval(i) = timeit(@() useEval(f, N));
  timeEvalHandle(i) = timeit(@() useEvalHandle(f, N));
  timeStr2func(i) = timeit(@() useStr2func(f, N));
end

figure
plot(Ns, timeEval, 'DisplayName', 'time eval');
hold on
plot(Ns, timeEvalHandle, 'DisplayName', 'time eval');
hold on
plot(Ns, timeStr2func, 'DisplayName', 'time str2func');
legend show
xlabel('N');

figure
plot(Ns, timeEval./timeStr2func, 'DisplayName', 'time_{eval}/time_{str2func}');
hold on
plot(Ns, timeEvalHandle./timeStr2func, 'DisplayName', 'time_{eval handle}/time_{str2func}');
legend show
xlabel('N');

figure
plot(Ns, timeEvalHandle./timeStr2func);
ylabel('time_{eval handle}/time_{str2func}')
xlabel('N');

function y = useEval(f, N)
  a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4;
  for x=1:N
    y = eval(f);
  end
end

function y = useEvalHandle(f, N)
  a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4;
  fHandle = eval(['@(x, a, b, c, d) ' f]);
  for x=1:N
    y = fHandle(x, a, b, c, d);
  end
end

function y = useStr2func(f, N)
  a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4;
  fHandle = str2func(['@(x, a, b, c, d) ' f]);
  for x=1:N
    y = fHandle(x, a, b, c, d);
  end
end
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**`str2func` vs `eval` (without function handle):** The results show that even for evaluating the function once, it is around 50% faster to use `str2func` than `eval` (without function handle). For a large number of evaluations, `str2func` may be around 100x faster (depending on the function you are evaluating).

**`str2func` vs `eval` (with function handle):** `eval` is around 100% slower than `str2func` for a single evaluation, but becomes are almost equally fast for a large number of evaluations (`eval` is ~5% slower).

**`eval` with and without function handle:** Note that for a single evaluation creating a function handle with `eval` is ~50% slower than evaluating it directly.

**Conclusion:** `str2func` is always faster than `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

In the following benchmark a collection of function handles is created and performance of `eval` is compare to that of `str2func` to evaluate strings. The functions are combination of variables with +- signs.

```
n = 16;
op=char((dec2bin(0:2^n-1)-48)*2+43);
vars= 'a':'z';
v = vars(1:n+1);
s(1:2^n,1:2:2*n+1)=repmat(v,2^n,1);
s(:,2:2:end)=op;

h=repmat(['@(' sprintf('%c,',v(1:end-1)) v(end) ')'],2^n,1);
farray=[h,s];
tic
for k = 1:2^n
    f = eval(farray(k,:));
end
toc

tic
for k = 1:2^n
    f = str2func(farray(k,:));
end
toc
```

Result in Octave:

There is no difference between two methods.

Comment: Matlab result: `Elapsed time is 62.920203 seconds.
Elapsed time is 60.706978 seconds.`